# How to set a menu hover delay

Tags: jquery, html, css

Working example:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txdjyt7t/1/

So I have a UL/LI menu and when I hover over the different headings then different options are shown. If I hover over "Link 2" in the example and then slightly hover over "Link 3" on my way down to select an option, then it changes what is displayed because of the on `mouseenter` event. While I understand this is how it is coded, I want to know if I can set a small delay so it ignores that slight hover over "Link 3" and just keeps the "Link 2" content visible.

HTML

```
<div id="navCategories">
<div class="wrapper">       
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <!--<li><a href="my_account">My Account</a></li>-->
            <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Link 2 <div class="oclmenu openmenu"></div></a>
            <div class="nav-div">
                <ul class="nav-blocks">
                    <li><a href="what-is-#-pbx"><span>1</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="business-#-pbx-plans"><span>2</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>3</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#" class="menuLink">Link 3 <div class="oclmenu openmenu"></div></a>
            <div class="nav-div">
                <ul class="nav-blocks">
                    <li><a href="what-is-#-pbx"><span>A</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="business-#-pbx-plans"><span>B</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>C</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    </div>
</div>  
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {       
        if (!$("#showCat").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).find("div").fadeIn(0);
            $(this).find("ul").fadeIn(0);
        }
    },

    mouseleave: function () {
        if (!$("#showCat").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).find("div").fadeOut(0);
            $(this).find("ul").fadeOut(0);
        }
    }
}, "#nav ul li");
```

CSS

```
#navCategories { position: relative; background: #006bb2; width: 1131px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 65px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-top-left-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #999 !important;  }
#navSpacer { border-top: 0px solid #b7ccdb; border-bottom: 0px solid #fff; margin-top: 20px; }
#nav { margin-left: 10px; }
#nav ul, #nav ul ul { z-index: 10; width: 1131px; }
#nav ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; margin-top: 10px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; }
#nav ul div { border: 1px solid #999; border-top: 0px; display: none; width: 100%; height: 170px; padding: 10px; top: 55px; position: absolute; left: -10px; background: #fff; box-sizing: border-box; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; }
#nav ul ul { display: none; position: relative; float: left; background: #fff; width: 20%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
#nav ul ul li { float: none; margin-right: 0px;  }
#nav ul .nav-blocks { width: auto; }
#nav ul .nav-blocks li { float: left; margin-right: 0px; }
#nav ul .nav-blocks li a { height: 150px; width: 180px; display: block; padding: 0px; font-size: 17px !important; background-position: 50% 40% !important; background-repeat: no-repeat !important; position: relative; }
#nav ul .nav-blocks li a span { position: absolute; bottom: 15px; width: 180px; left: 0px; text-indent: 0px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; text-align: center; }
#nav ul .nav-blocks li a:hover { }
#nav ul ul li a { height: 35px; color: #444 !important; line-height: 35px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; border-radius: 5px; }
#nav ul ul li a:link,#nav ul ul li a:visited { font-size: 14px; color: #ccc; text-transform: none; }
#nav ul ul li a:hover,#nav ul ul li a:active { color: #fff; background-color: #e2f3ff !important; }
#nav ul > li:hover  > a { color: #000 !important; background: #fff;  }
#nav ul li { float: left; margin: 0px; }
#nav ul li a { display: block; padding: 0px 20px; height: 55px; line-height: 45px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-top-left-radius: 5px; color: #fff !important;  }
#nav ul .nav-list li a { border-radius: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; text-indent: 25px; font-size: 17px !important; height: 50px; line-height: 50px; background: url("../img/navigation/arrow.png") no-repeat 10px 51% !important;  }
#nav ul .nav-list { padding-left: 15px; }
#nav ul .nav-list li { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; box-sizing: border-box; }
#nav ul .nav-list li:last-child { border-bottom: 0px; }
#nav ul li a:hover { background: #fff; color: #444 !important; }
```

Comment: Try transitions: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Have a look at [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) this could help you

Comment: I would prefer not to use a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else interested in this, I worked out how to set a delay between each menu option.

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/txdjyt7t/6/

Instead of `display: none` on the `li div`, I needed to use `visibility: hidden` and use `visibility: visible` to show it. I then used a transition-delay on each `visible` and `hidden`.

No jQuery is needed any more.

CSS:

```
#navCategories { position: relative; background: #006bb2; width: 1131px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 65px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-top-left-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #999 !important;  }
#navSpacer { border-top: 0px solid #b7ccdb; border-bottom: 0px solid #fff; margin-top: 20px; }
#nav { margin-left: 10px; }
#nav ul, #nav ul ul { z-index: 10; width: 1131px; }
#nav ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; margin-top: 10px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; }
#nav ul div { border: 1px solid #999; border-top: 0px; visibility: hidden; width: 100%; height: 170px; padding: 10px; top: 55px; position: absolute; left: -10px; background: #fff; box-sizing: border-box; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; }
#nav ul ul { visibility: hidden; display: block; position: relative; float: left; background: #fff; width: 20%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
#nav ul ul li { float: none; margin-right: 0px;  }
#nav ul .nav-blocks { width: auto; }
#nav ul .nav-blocks li { float: left; margin-right: 0px; }
#nav ul .nav-blocks li a { height: 150px; width: 180px; display: block; padding: 0px; font-size: 17px !important; background-position: 50% 40% !important; background-repeat: no-repeat !important; position: relative; }
#nav ul .nav-blocks li a span { position: absolute; bottom: 15px; width: 180px; left: 0px; text-indent: 0px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; text-align: center; }
#nav ul .nav-blocks li a:hover { }
#nav ul ul li a { height: 35px; color: #444 !important; line-height: 35px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; border-radius: 5px; }
#nav ul ul li a:link,#nav ul ul li a:visited { font-size: 14px; color: #ccc; text-transform: none; }
#nav ul ul li a:hover,#nav ul ul li a:active { color: #fff; background-color: #e2f3ff !important; }

/* Transition-delay */
#nav > ul > li > a,#nav > ul > li,#nav > ul > li div,#nav > ul > li ul,#nav > ul > li:hover  > a,#nav > ul > li:hover div,#nav > ul > li:hover ul  { transition-delay: 0.1s; }

#nav > ul > li:hover  > a { color: #000 !important; background: #fff; }
#nav > ul > li:hover div { visibility: visible; }
#nav > ul > li:hover ul { visibility: visible; }
#nav ul li { float: left; margin: 0px; }
#nav ul li a { display: block; padding: 0px 20px; height: 55px; line-height: 45px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-top-left-radius: 5px; color: #fff !important;  }
#nav ul .nav-list li a { border-radius: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; text-indent: 25px; font-size: 17px !important; height: 50px; line-height: 50px; background: url("../img/navigation/arrow.png") no-repeat 10px 51% !important;  }
#nav ul .nav-list { padding-left: 15px; }
#nav ul .nav-list li { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; box-sizing: border-box; }
#nav ul .nav-list li:last-child { border-bottom: 0px; }
#nav ul li a:hover { background: #fff; color: #444 !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use transition property for delay in hover.

```
#nav ul > li:hover  > a { color: #000 !important; background: #fff; -webkit-transition:2s; -moz-transition:2s }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/txdjyt7t/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set delay in the animation of jQuery you should set it inside function for example .fadeIn(1000) // 1000ms for 1 second

you can try

```
    $(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {       
        if (!$("#showCat").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).find("div").fadeIn(1000);
            $(this).find("ul").fadeIn(1000);
        }
    },

    mouseleave: function () {
        if (!$("#showCat").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).find("div").fadeOut(1000);
            $(this).find("ul").fadeOut(1000);
        }
    }
}, "#nav ul li");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/txdjyt7t/4/)**

**CSS:**

```
li:hover > a {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;

}
```